# jquery saving form input into an array of objects then displaying them, getting uncaught typeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am currently working on a bootstrap-styled form that allows a person to enter a handler and a comment.It has a button that, when clicked, will call a jquery event handler that saves the handler,comment, and Date.now() in an object that will be pushed in the array users.

However, I keep getting

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'handler' of undefined at HTMLButtonElement.,at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch,at HTMLButtonElement.v.handle."

The error is from the .js file line : $("#display").val......

Form and display area code

```
<form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">handle</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="handle" placeholder="@joe">
        </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Comment</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="comm" rows="3" placeholder="Bad match last night, Joe sucked"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button id="button1" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
</form>
<h1 id="display"></h1>
```

jquery .js file

```
    $(document).ready(
function(){
var users = [];
$("#button1").click(function(){
    var person={
                handler:$("#handle").val(),
                comment:$("#comm").val(),
                postDate:Date.now()
               };

users.push(person);


$("#display").val(users[0].person.handler+"<br>"+users[0].person.comment);


     });
});
```

I am new to jquery and thus I am not sure how to fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

`users[0].person.handler` should be `users[0].handler`. The variable is named `person`, but the array itself doesn't care about that. Same thing for `users[0].person.comment`.

Edit: Also, you might need an `preventDefault()` call to stop the page from refreshing (unless that's what you want.

```
$("#button1").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var person = {
    handler:$("#handle").val(),
    comment:$("#comm").val(),
    postDate:Date.now()
  };

  users.push(person);

  // i changed this to .html() because val() felt wrong
  $("#display").html(users[0].handler+"<br>"+users[0].comment);
});
```

Comment: did that, the error went away. But the values didnt display

Comment: I changed `.val()` to `.html()` to make them show up; `.val()` doesn't really do much for h1 tags.

Answer (score 0):

Use `users[0].handler` instead of `users[0].person.handler`. Although the variable is named person, what is actually pushed into the `users` Array is just a reference to the `person` Object.

Also, use the `.html()` method to set the `innerHTML` of the `#display` h1 as a `h1` does not have a value attribute.

```js
$(document).ready(
function(){
var users = [];
$("#button1").click(function(e){
    var person={
                handler:$("#handle").val(),
                comment:$("#comm").val(),
                postDate:Date.now()
               };

users.push(person);

e.preventDefault();
$("#display").html(users[0].handler+"<br>"+users[0].comment);


     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">handle</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="handle" placeholder="@joe">
        </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Comment</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="comm" rows="3" placeholder="Bad match last night, Joe sucked"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button id="button1" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
</form>
<h1 id="display"></h1>
```

Comment: did that, the error went away. But the values didnt display

Comment: @AlanO'Brian Did you run the code snippet? It worked fine for me.

Comment: @AlanO'Brian No problem.